# How to split a patch into two parts (with pbranch)?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension

I am working on a mercurial repository and using [pbrach](http://arrenbrecht.ch/mercurial/pbranch/) for working on a set of patches.

Assume I have two files A and B, and two patches patchA (modifies A) and patchAB (modifies A and B).
The pgraph looks like this:

```
o  patchAB
|
@  patchA
|
o  default
```

By mistake, I committed a change to file B into patchA.

How do I split the patch A into 2 parts, so that I end up with: patchA=patchA' + newPatch, where patchA=Original Patch, patchA'=changes of patchA in file A, P2=changes of patchA in file B.

```
o  patchAB
|
| o newPatch // rest of original patchA without changes already in patchA'
|/
@  patchA' // with only the changes to file A
|
o  default
```

(I search something similar to [splitting patches with mq](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqTutorial#Splitting_by_files) but for pbranch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a relatively short solution myself.

First I get the revision number of the last 'good' commit (say 1), and the wrong commit (say 2).

1) I update to patchA, revert the change on fileB, and commit it, and pmerge the changes upwards:

```
hg up patchA
hg revert -r1 fileB  // get fileB before the wrong change
hg commit -m"revert fileB"
hg pmerge -a
```

2) Update to patchA again, revert the wrong commit and create a new patch:

```
hg up patchA
hg revert -r2 fileB  // get fileB after the wrong change
hg pnew patchA2
```

We now have the changes of fileA in patchA and the rest in patchA2.